# Deliberate Shoot-Through in H-bridge for EMI reduction

Tags: h-bridge, emc, shoot-through

today I was analysing an H-bridge driver circuit in a commercial product which is used to drive a DC motor (approx 24V/4A) over an unshielded cable with about 1.5m length. When I did a simulation of the H-bridge I saw that shoot-through appears in every switching cycle. Even though the current waveform shows high spikes, the node voltage is rising and falling extremely smooth. This seems to be quite logical because you never have a reverse recovery overshoot of a clamping body diode.

For me it looks very difficult to surely stay withing the MOSFETs SOA considering all the device tolerances (driver is discrete), variation of threshold voltage vs. temperature and so on. The only thing to limit the current seems to be the long trace of the supply line (~50mOhm an a few nanoH), the ESR of the Elko and a small fuse.

Is this a good design practice or has anyone of you ever seen this approach to reduce dv/dt-induced EMI?

Comment: How do you know it was shoot thru?

Comment: I checked VGS and ID of Highside and Lowside MOSFET. VGS of a MOSFET in turnoff was still around 2V when the VGS of the complementary MOSFET was already in the plateau region. The drain current shows a very sharp spike which looks almost perfectly triangular as if both MOSFETs were in saturation. And I never saw any of the body diodes clamp.

Comment: I have heard of this on a 24V lead acid wheelchair controller .